# how to get adobe flash fullscreen video fluid with an atom processor?

Tags: 12.04, video, intel-graphics, intel, hd-video

My system has an atom N270 + intel i915 graphic card.

Under Windows I can enjoy 720p bigbuckbunny youtube video fullscreen without any trouble.

Under Ubuntu 12.04 I have laggy and choppy fullscreen video and choppy video when not fullscreen.

I've seen that under ubuntu the cpu is almost always at 100% use.

What I must do in order to have videos playing well under ubuntu ?

**I've already tried the following :**

**Force flash gpu detection : (no result) :**

- mkdir /etc/adobe
- echo "OverrideGPUValidation = 1" | sudo tee -a /etc/adobe/mms.cfg

**grub options (had results but not enough) :**

- i915_enable_rc6=1
- i915_enable_fbc=1
- i915_lvds_downclock=1
- pcie_aspm=force

**updated intel drivers (glasen ppa)**

**Using chrome instead of firefox (had impact but not enough)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flash under linux does not support hardware acceleration. So instead of your graphics accelerator your CPU has to do all the audio/video decoding, which makes playback laggy. You have several options here. You could

- Enable [HTML5 playback](http://www.youtube.com/html5) and see if that fixes the issue for you (works on youtube and a couple of other sites).

  Not all youtube videos currently support HTML5 playback. To bypass this limitation you can install [Youtube Center](https://github.com/YePpHa/YouTubeCenter/wiki/Developer-Version), an open-source extension that's compatible with Chrome, Firefox and other popular web browsers.

  Aside from making HTML5 playback available across the board, Youtube Center also comes with *a lot* of other features that can greatly enhance your youtube experience.
- Play the video with VLC (open up vlc, hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste your video link and hit enter)
- Use a dedicated youtube client such as [minitube](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/09/desktop-youtube-app-minitube-adds-search-filtering-youtube-fix)
- Install [ViewTube](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/87011), a userscript that allows you to play flash videos on sites like youtube, dailymotion, blip, etc. in a video player of your choice

These are workarounds rather than definitive solutions. But until Adobe decide to fully support Linux again there is nothing else, I fear.

Comment: would be nice to know if and when they will fix it. I have the feeling it used to be less worse with older versions of flash and firefox, could this be the case? If so one could think of rolling back a few versions.

Comment: @AndreaBorga Yes, I think Adobe Flash on Linux supported hardware acceleration for a while. As far as I recall it was restricted to Nvidia hardware (via the VDPAU interface). I would advise against installing an obsolete version of flash to get this working again as it poses a major risk to your security. Adobe Flash is one of the main vectors for malware.

Comment: @AndreaBorga There's also [this webupd8 article](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/09/adobe-flash-player-hardware.html) I had saved a few months back. Wasn't very stable for me when I tried it out (flash player would frequently crash). But you could give it a try if you have an Intel card.