# Flash player alternative for firefox

Tags: firefox, flash

I am searching for an flash player alternative for firefox

Yes I am using chrome and I know that it has its own flash version however I am used to Firefox, and it is hard not to have videos in firefox.

So what I want is to get flash running on firefox without using adobe outdated flash plugin.

I asked this question on Firefox support community.
this is the answer I got
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/993679

I tried installing Gnash and Lightspark they did not work then I tried to install the 32-bit versions of this software they did not work as well.

So does anyone knows how to get flash videos working in firefox ??

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I have a question have you read my post on askubuntu???

Comment: If watching videos is your main concern there are different solutions available to bypass flash. E.g. [this userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/87011) for greaseoneky (a popular Firefox extension) that let's you play videos on youtube, dailymotion and other sites via Totem/VLC. Please see [my answer here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/194545/how-to-get-adobe-flash-fullscreen-video-fluid-with-an-atom-processor/194576#194576) for options (in this case concerning youtube, specifically).

Comment: @Levan have you read this >> But if you have the required Gstreamer dependencies, you can play videos on many sites in HTML5 format.

    https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/youtube-all-html5/
    https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/video-without-flash/
    http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/87011

Comment: @panchalsag Thank you very much for your reply yes I have tried that but I am looking for something a bit more something like a flesh emulator.

Comment: @Levan You can go to this link and request html5 video player it will retire flash. [Youtube HTML5 Request] (https://www.youtube.com/html5)

Comment: @panchalsag thank you again for your reply but ytube is note a priority here I would like to have flash player emulator or something similar for other websites mostly.

Comment: maybe downgraded/portable FF will do https://askubuntu.com/questions/958539/how-to-install-firefox-55/987267#987267

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you search for flash player alternative only because the adobe flash plugin for linux is outdated, you could install the latest version of the adobe flash player through [pipelight](http://pipelight.net/cms/installation.html) which allows you to use its supported plugins nearly as if you use windows browser.

then you could keep the plugins up-to-date using `sudo pipelight-plugin  --update`