# How to install Firefox 55?

Tags: firefox, software-center

My last Firefox upgrade made it into FF 57.0b2.  I attempted to remove the software, but instead I completely removed Firefox. Including the hidden files, and the files in /etc and /usr. Restarted Ubuntu. 
Installed Firefox from the Software center. And once again, 57.0b2 is installed again.

How do I install version 55? On the Mozilla site I can download firefox-55.0.3.tar.bz2, I don't know how to install .bz2 files.

Comment: .tar.bz|gz are called tarballs; tar makes many files/directories into a single-file, and the gzip/bzip compresses them; so if you used windoze it's like a .cab/.rar/.zip.  gzip is quick compression used on the internet (your browser decodes), bzip is like maximum compression (looking for patterns thru data).  commands will expand it, or use  your favorite file-browser to click & expand it  (given you used software-centre this will be you).  it'll have a readme file that tells you how; if its source it'll tell you to make; make install, but just follow its directions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You don't need to install with the downloaded Firefox package and it's probably a bad idea.**

How did you installed **Firefox 57.0b2** in the first place? (Rhetorical question)

Firefox 57.0b2 is the **Firefox DevEdition** version. In Ubuntu, Ubuntu flavors and derivatives, the usual and recommended way to get this unstable version is with the [Firefox DevEdition PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-aurora). Based on this report

> Installed Firefox from the Software center. And presto! my nightmare is back. FF 57.0b2 again.

I suspect that you took the most common route as described above. If so, whilst the PPA is there that should be expected.

**How to *downgrade* to the stable version as provided by the official Ubuntu repositories:**

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [website](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux), it suggests that firefox in its archive form is "extract and run". You dont actually "install" it. If you want to "install" it on your system, you have to move the extracted firefox folder to `/usr/lib`, remove the old one and copy the new one from the archive. Be sure to make a backup of the original firefox folder just in case your current config files conflict with the version you extracted to `/usr/lib`.

All other symlinks should still work. if they dont, you need to recreate them to `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ubuntu-browsers.d` and `/usr/bin`

Answer (score 0):

- see https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/ and download your version
- unzip to any folder
- from the unzipped folder remove the "updater" file so it cant update
- run with "firefox" from unzipped folder
- you can change the path to your profile  buy running firefox -profile [path to profile]
- you can have multiple versions.. its a standalone(portable) application
- see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_Entries to create a desktop entry on your desktop

Answer (score 0):

```
tar xvf firefox-55.0.3.tar.bz2
cd firefox/
./firefox
```

now open Preferences and click Set as default, this creates `~/.local/share/applications/userapp-Firefox-[random].desktop` and adds entries to `~/.config/mimeapps.list`

that's it, this firefox should now handle any web associations from applications like your file manager

to have a desktop icon / launcher remove `NoDisplay` from and add `Icon=firefox` to `~/.local/share/applications/userapp-Firefox-[random].desktop` and copy the icons (see link)

[see how to install firefox from mozilla](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/firefox-reinstall-4175627559/#post5845618)

auto updates work like in the windows version and if you want to keep the version you initially downloaded you should disable them